# Kendo UI Styling with Many Django Forms

Tags: django, kendo-ui

We have a Django project that has many (100s) of forms across it.  We would like to apply Kendo UI styling (http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/styling/index) to all of our forms.  This pretty much entails adding classes to the appropriate elements in order to get the styling.

What's the best technique to achieve this result?  I've found two main approaches, each with their drawbacks:

1 - Create a "Kendo Form" Django template.  This template would have tons of logic in it for each type of possible field.  However, this would probably be the easier of the two options for application authors to use (just include the template on their pages).  Would we also lose functionality like `.as_p()` and `.as_table()`?

```
{% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
    {{ hidden }}
{% endfor %}

{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    {% if field|is_choice %}
        <stuff class="niftyKendoClass"></stuff>
    {% elif field|is_radio %}
        <stuff class="niftyKendoClass"></stuff>
    ......
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

2 - Create custom "Kendo Widgets" by subclassing Django's widgets (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/widgets).  From what I can tell, implementation of this technique would be easier than the template since I just need CSS classes and can reuse Django's markup in most cases, but it becomes harder on the caller as their form declaration becomes heavier.

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    field = forms.CharField(widget=forms.KendoTextInput())
```

---

Of course, both of these options are to avoid scattered classes across all of the Django applications, which are very painful if we ever change styling for forms.

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    field = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'class': 'niftyKendoClass'}
        )
    )
```